# Converting a InstallShield MSI/Project to NSIS

Tags: installation, windows-installer, nsis, installshield

I have an MSI built with Installshield. I want to decrease the size of the MSI, so I was looking at other options. It seems like NSIS has LZMA compression which is better than whatever is used by InstallShield. Is there an easy way to convert my MSI or InstallShield Project to a NSIS (or any other installer with Better Compression) project & build it.

Comment: MSI has advantages like transactional behavior. I wouldn't consider to switch to NSIS. At least WiX allows to create compressed MSI files (http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_file.htm). But I assume InstallShield would do it too.

Comment: @harper Both Wix & Installshield have compression, but not LZMA compression.

Comment: From InstallShield 2011 support LZX and MSZIP compression.

Comment: For smaller projects NSIS is better as it had overhead only 32 kB. Creating MSI for small project produces HUGE file even with zero functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for some tool or utility?

There is nothing like that.

Only way is to rewrite advanced features of your MSI into NSIS manually (but the basic skeleton of installer - pages, files, shortcuts, registry keys, ini values, ... can be generated by enclosed Wizard).